# Rotation of a matrix through $\cfrac{-\pi}{4}$

Tags: matrices, rotations

So this is my question.

$T:R2→R2$ rotates points (about the origin) through $\cfrac{-\pi}{4}$ (clock-wise)

So what I do know that I need is that the origin is represented as 
$$ T =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    cos \theta &-sin\theta \\
    sin \theta & cos \theta \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then I know that rotation is $\cfrac{-\pi}{4}$.

I was also given the hint that $$T(e_1) = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2  \\
    -1/\sqrt2  & 1/\sqrt2  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm not exactly sure how to proceed with this to get $$T(e_1)$$ I'm thinking I need to do something like

$$ T =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    cos (-\pi/4) &-sin(-\pi/4) \\
    sin (-\pi/4) & cos (-\pi/4) \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Am I headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You are in the good direction.

Comment: That's what I concluded just now. I'm still new to the whole cos and sin of an angle type of math so I wasn't sure if this is what I was supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

So just in case, anyone is wondering. I came to the $ T(e_1) $ answer by using output of $ cos(-\pi/4)$, $-sin(-\pi/4)$, $sin(-\pi/4)$, and $cos(-\pi/4)$ because $cos(-\pi/4)$ is  $1/\sqrt2$, $-sin(-\pi/4)$ is $1/\sqrt2$, $sin(-\pi/4)$ is $-(1/\sqrt2)$, and $cos(-\pi/4)$ is $1/\sqrt2$. This concludes to $ T(e_1) =  
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2  \\
    -1/\sqrt2  & 1/\sqrt2  \\
    \end{bmatrix} $